# Function parameters when variables values are not set

Tags: php

How can I call a function without throwing any errors when certain variables are not set?

For example, I need to `logUserActivity($uName,$uId)`. This'll work ok if a user is logged in and both those variables are set. However, it will not work if a user is not logged in, and will throw an error.

In that case can, something be done to make those two values NULL?

I did this: `logUserActivity($uName=NULL,$uId=NULL)` but this makes them forever NULL.

I also did `function logUserActivity($uName=NULL, $uId=NULL)`, by this still throws an error.

Comment: function logUserActivity($uName=NULL, $uId=NULL) should work fine make sure you are checking them against null before doing any process.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set default value of a function to make it optional

Like try this

```
function logUserActivity($uName='', $uId='')
```

Comment: what's about when invoking: `logUserActivity(null,null);`? it seems the OP has this scenario in their question.

Answer (score 0):

```
function logUserActivity($uName=NULL, $uId=NULL){
  if($uName != ''){
     echo 'Uname is set - '.$uName;
  }
  if($uId != ''){
     echo 'uId is set - '.$uId;
  }
}

logUserActivity(NULL,20);//O/p - uId is set - 20
logUserActivity('Test',NULL);//O/p - Uname is set - Test
logUserActivity('Test',20);//O/p - uId is set - 20,uId is set - 20
logUserActivity(NULL,NULL);//NO O/p
```

Answer (score 0):

Write like this:

```
function logUserActivity($uName=NULL, $uId=NULL) // If nothing is passed it will take it as null
    {
     if($uName==NULL && $uId == NULL) {
      //User is not logged in
      }
      else
      {
        //user is logged in
      }
    }
```

And Call it as when user is logged in

```
logUserActivity("userName", 12345);
```

And When user is not logged in

```
logUserActivity();
```

For more information you can check this out:https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function logUserActivity($uName=null,$uId=null) {
    if ( !isset($uName) || !$uName ) {
        $uName = 'some default'; // optionally, return; could be sued
    }
    if ( !isset($uId) || !$uId) {
        $uId = 'some default'; // optionally, return; could be sued
    }
}
```